# Microsoft access query with duplicate numbers in a field

Tags: database, ms-access

Please help. I have a access database designed for a small school. After the exams the students are awarded certificates based on the ranking position based on the exam results. The problem is there are duplicate students with the same overall marks and I would like to check who has had the highest mid year marks to then award an extra mark to the student with the highest mid year exam marks to decide their Ranking position. If there are still duplicate marks, than I would like to check the effort marks to check who has had the highest and then award an addition mark to illuminate duplicates but to achieve a ranking position without any duplicates. 
Can anyone help using access query.

Comment: By 'duplicate students with the same overall marks' do you mean 'more than one student with the same overall marks'? I don't understand 'an addition mark'. Do you mean additional? I don't understand 'illuminate duplicates'.

Comment: In the query, arrange the 4 scores from left to right and sort on all of them.    That will list all students in the rank order you want.  Then look at the query properties and set the TOP VALUES property to the number of students you want to select.  If 2 students are equal on all 4 scores there will still be a duplicate - so you might want to set TOP VALUES to include another student or two and visually look for ties for last place.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, to make it clearer the database has other fields that determine the Rank or position of the student in the class. The other fields are Effort marks that are awarded each week to the students who have had 100% attendance, there are mid year exam marks that are considered for the final ranking. The overall marks are the sum of end of year marks + mid year marks + Effort marks.